# Click function on Toggle Buttons in Unreal Engine 4 C++

Tags: c++, user-interface, unreal-engine4, unreal-umg

I have a doubt about CheckBoxes and click events. I have some button which executes a function OnClick, something like this on code:

`SomeButton->OnClicked.AddDynamic(this, &ClassName::FunctionToExecute);`

For style reasons, I thought that I should use a Toggle Button, implemented with a CheckBox, instead of a regular Button. However, I am having trouble finding the correct method to bind the function to each click. So far, I tried something like this, but it doesn't work. I also tried declaring a delegate, but it won't work either.

`SomeCheckBox->OnCheckStateChanged.Add(&ClassName::FunctionToExecute);`

What is the correct way to bind the function to the OnCheckStateChanged() event?
Thanks a lot in advance :smile:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a UMG Check box (which it sounds like you are), than we can look at the delegate declaration:

```
// In Checkbox.h 
DECLARE_DYNAMIC_MULTICAST_DELEGATE_OneParam( FOnCheckBoxComponentStateChanged, bool, bIsChecked );
```

and notice that we need a *bool* input parameter for our callback function.

So that means that our callback function has to look like this:

```
void UYourWidget::OnCheckboxChanged(bool bIsChecked) {}
```

You can then bind your widget like this:

```
if(CheckBox)
{
    CheckBox->OnCheckStateChanged.AddDynamic(this, &UTextChatWidget::Test);
}
```

If you are using a slate check box, then the callback function declaration is a bit different. It uses the ECheckBoxState enum instead of a boolean.

```
SNew(SCheckBox)
   .OnCheckStateChanged(this, &SFoo::OnStateChanged)

void SFoo::OnStateChanged(ECheckBoxState NewState) {}
```

My typical approach for figuring this stuff out is to simply do a `CTRL+SHIFT+F` search for the delegate in Visual Studio to find other examples of it.

Comment: Nice, this sounds exactly like what I was looking for. I was hoping there was a way to bind the callback function without creating a new UCheckBox based class (in the same way I don't need to modify UButtons to bind OnClick functions to them).
Thanks a lot for the answer! :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)